# Azure media services how is cost calculated with streaming units?

Tags: azure, streaming, video-streaming, azure-media-services, price

If I use a streaming unit for content hosted on windows azure media services, do I still pay for the Network out costs in per GB associated with the content being streamed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I still pay for the Network out costs in per GB associated with the
>   content being streamed?

Yes. Based on the information provided on the [`pricing page`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/media-services/), you get charged for both. From the pricing page:

> Deliver on-demand and live video streams to customers in multiple
>   formats and at scale. **Streaming is billed by the amount of data
>   transferred and Streaming Units required**. When Azure CDN is not
>   enabled for a Streaming Endpoint, data transfer is charged at Data
>   Transfer pricing. When Azure CDN is enabled for a Streaming Endpoint,
>   data transfer charges do not apply. Data transferred is instead just
>   charged at standard CDN pricing.